# Disqus: is it possible to post from foreign identity

Tags: oauth, identity, disqus

I develop ios-application and my target is to deploy Disqus comments to app.

Is it possible to post comments from foreign identity? (Facebook, Twitter, etc)?
I found this post to Disqus developers google [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/disqus-dev/8F6c5QV4aPE).

Also, i have found this example, which implements [Disqus](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/iadisquser).
But it uses email and nickname.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the only authentication that's supported with the API is:

1. Disqus accounts
2. Single Sign-on (SSO)
3. Using the permissions of the website owner (to post unregistered guest comments)

You can find more information here: http://disqus.com/api/docs/auth/